# Additional tool in window phone emulator not enabled

Tags: visual-studio-2013, window, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-cordova, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have been trying to deploy visual studio Apache cordova tool project on  window phone emulator but i am getting the following error.

> windows phone emulator wasn't able to connect to the windows phone
>   operating system the phone didn't respond to the connect request.

When i click okay the Additional tool(>>) icon is not enable. and there is no internet on the emulator.i have remove and re install Hyper-V but is not seem to be working. I am in a Domain network with DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

can you install the Windows Phone virtual switch in Hyper-V Manager and let us know if that resolves the issue?